# How can I resolve the "OSError: [WinError 998]" error when using pyarmor with pyinstaller in Python?

Tags: pyinstaller, python-3.10, pyarmor

my command is here,was working before but this morning when I tried to build my program I got this error...

pyarmor-7 pack -e "--onefile --hidden-import=pywintypes --icon=weapons/icon.ico" .\calistir.py

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\emrovsky\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 198, in <module>
    run()
  File "C:\Users\emrovsky\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 180, in run
    run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
  File "C:\Users\emrovsky\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 61, in run_build
    PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\emrovsky\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 1019, in main
    build(specfile, distpath, workpath, clean_build)
  File "C:\Users\emrovsky\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 944, in build
    exec(code, spec_namespace)
  File "calistir-patched.spec", line 7, in <module>
    a = Analysis(
  File "C:\Users\emrovsky\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 429, in __init__
    self.__postinit__()
  File "C:\Users\emrovsky\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\datastruct.py", line 184, in __postinit__
    self.assemble()
  File "C:\Users\emrovsky\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 745, in assemble
    isolated.call(find_binary_dependencies, self.binaries, self.binding_redirects, collected_packages)
  File "C:\Users\emrovsky\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\PyInstaller\isolated\_parent.py", line 372, in call
    return isolated.call(function, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\emrovsky\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\PyInstaller\isolated\_parent.py", line 302, in call
    raise RuntimeError(f"Child process call to {function.__name__}() failed with:\n" + output)
RuntimeError: Child process call to find_binary_dependencies() failed with:
  File "C:\Users\emrovsky\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\win32ctypes\pywin32\pywintypes.py", line 33, in pywin32error
    yield
  File "C:\Users\emrovsky\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\win32ctypes\pywin32\win32api.py", line 64, in EnumResourceTypes
    _resource._EnumResourceTypes(
  File "C:\Users\emrovsky\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\win32ctypes\core\cffi\_resource.py", line 66, in _EnumResourceTypes
    check_false(
  File "C:\Users\emrovsky\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\win32ctypes\core\cffi\_util.py", line 78, in __call__
    self._raise_error(function_name)
  File "C:\Users\emrovsky\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\win32ctypes\core\cffi\_util.py", line 89, in _raise_error
    raise exception
OSError: [WinError 998] Bellek konumuna geçersiz erişim

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\emrovsky\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\PyInstaller\isolated\_child.py", line 63, in run_next_command
    output = function(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\emrovsky\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 187, in find_binary_dependencies
    return bindepend.Dependencies(binaries, redirects=binding_redirects, xtrapath=extra_libdirs)
  File "C:\Users\emrovsky\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\bindepend.py", line 275, in Dependencies
    for ftocnm, fn in getAssemblyFiles(pth, manifest, redirects):
  File "C:\Users\emrovsky\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\bindepend.py", line 449, in getAssemblyFiles
    for assembly in getAssemblies(pth):
  File "C:\Users\emrovsky\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\bindepend.py", line 403, in getAssemblies
    res = winmanifest.GetManifestResources(pth)
  File "C:\Users\emrovsky\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\win32\winmanifest.py", line 979, in GetManifestResources
    return winresource.GetResources(filename, [RT_MANIFEST], names, languages)
  File "C:\Users\emrovsky\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\win32\winresource.py", line 156, in GetResources
    res = _GetResources(hsrc, types, names, languages)
  File "C:\Users\emrovsky\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\win32\winresource.py", line 141, in _GetResources
    raise exception
  File "C:\Users\emrovsky\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\win32\winresource.py", line 111, in _GetResources
    enum_types = win32api.EnumResourceTypes(hsrc)
  File "C:\Users\emrovsky\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\win32ctypes\pywin32\win32api.py", line 63, in EnumResourceTypes
    with _pywin32error():
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\contextlib.py", line 153, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(typ, value, traceback)
  File "C:\Users\emrovsky\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\win32ctypes\pywin32\pywintypes.py", line 37, in pywin32error
    raise error(exception.winerror, exception.function, exception.strerror)
win32ctypes.pywin32.pywintypes.error: (998, 'EnumResourceTypes', 'Bellek konumuna geçersiz erişim')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\emrovsky\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\Scripts\pyarmor-7.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\emrovsky\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pyarmor\pyarmor.py", line 1612, in main_entry
    main(sys.argv[1:])
  File "C:\Users\emrovsky\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pyarmor\pyarmor.py", line 1604, in main
    args.func(args)
  File "C:\Users\emrovsky\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pyarmor\packer.py", line 656, in packer
    _pyinstaller(src, entry, output, extra_options, xoptions, args)
  File "C:\Users\emrovsky\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pyarmor\packer.py", line 539, in _pyinstaller
    run_command([sys.executable] + initcmd + ['-y', '--clean', patched_spec])
  File "C:\Users\emrovsky\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pyarmor\packer.py", line 86, in run_command
    raise RuntimeError('Run command failed')
RuntimeError: Run command failed
```

I have tried many different methods like --add-data --hidden-imports but no luck..I've also read a lot of github issues, but I haven't come across many people with this problem.